# Hide Activity while loading until all content is loaded

Tags: android, android-activity

I would like to know if it is possible to hide and activity and his associated components until content is loaded. For example I retrieve an image from an url into an imageview, and there is always a delay until the image shows up. I want to hide it from the user with fading out the whole activity and just show a progressbar for example.

Can somebody please guide me on this topic?

Thanks!

I set the visibility in layout to invisible, like this:

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible" >
...
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Then I have a fragment class, following the onCreateView method:

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        profile_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_fragment_layout,
                container, false);


        return profile_view;

    }
```

After the AsynchTask is done, I try to set the visibility to visible, but the layout still is invisible:

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            /**
             * Checks for success message.
             **/
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {

                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);

                    String red = json.getString(KEY_ERROR);

                    if (Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {

                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        image_url = json_user.getString(KEY_AVATAR_PATH);

                        // ImageLoader class instance
                        ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getActivity());

                        imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, image_);


                        profile_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: set visibility=invisible on your main layout of activity xml. when all is up, set it programatically

Comment: I editet my question. I put code with my current efforts, but still no progress.

Comment: Why don't you use a splash screen fragment (which could have a progress bar) and then swap it out when your async task is finished?

Comment: try to set profile_view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) on onCreateView. and remove the xml android:visibility

Comment: Are you sure this statement reached and executed 
profile view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); ? because you have some conditions before it, what if one of those condition failed ? did you handle that situation ?

Comment: ok i will try the solution with the splash screen fragment. thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0):

You can put a full screen view, show it while loading and hide it after loaded.